# Calling Named Argument in PHP Function

Tags: php

I am a flutter developer and I used to use a function for example

```
String getVar({required String $a,bool $b = true}) {
  if($b){
    return $a;
  }
  else{
    return $a = 'error';
  }
}
```

So basically, $b = would be set as "true" by default we can modify it and $a should be filled

Calling Example:

```
getVar($a: 'input');
```

Here we can set $b to false anytime without making the order same as the required function

```
getVar($b: false, $a: 'input');
```

if it is in php, we should do like this

```
getVar($a: 'input',$b: false);
```

Now, here is the php code, making the same function

```
public function getVar(String $a = '',String $b = '',bool $c = true){
    if($c){
        return $a;
    }
    else{
        return $b;
    }
}
```

For example, I just want to set the last part which is $c

```
$this->getVar($c=false);
```

The main problem is $c is read as $a in the function

Comment: Remember that named arguments are a very new feature in PHP.  Until PHP 8, ALL arguments were passed sequentially.  There may be subtleties in the implementation that have simply not been worked out.  However, you should be able to write `$this->getVar(b: false, a: 'test');` in PHP 8.

Comment: which php version should be used then? I was trying to test it at http://phptester.net/ using php 8.1 but seems named arguments does not work

Comment: Look closely at your four examples of calling `getVar()`... compare the argument format. Also, I suggest you take a good look at the docs ~ https://www.php.net/manual/functions.arguments.php#functions.named-arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that named arguments are a very new feature in PHP.  Until PHP 8, ALL arguments were passed sequentially.  There may be subtleties in the implementation that have simply not been worked out.  However, you should be able to write

```
$this->getVar(b: false, a: 'test');
```

in PHP 8.  Looking at what you wrote:

```
$this->getVar($b=false, $a='test');
```

That doesn't do what you think.  That sets the local variable `$b` to `false`, and passes `false` as the first parameter, and sets the local variable `$a` to the string `'test'`, and passes that as the second parameter.  The `'='` operator already has a predefined meaning, so they had to introduce the `:` syntax for named parameters.

Comment: Thank you, so its basically almost same as Dart does. You saved my life!

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that the argument names should not have a `$` prefix (I know it's in your code examples but it might pay to state it clearly)

Comment: _"very new feature"_... [8.0.0 released 26th November 2020](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-8.php#8.0.0) . It's funny because 8.0 is already in maintenance and will be EOL in 5 months

Comment: Yeah, I'll take that criticism.  As a casual web developer, I find the rapid churn in PHP to be much more annoying than useful.  I want my tools to be stable, not fancy.